# How to create a 50 X 50 matrix in Python at runtime?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray

I have to create a 50 X 50 matrix in python at runtime using NumPy. The entries of the matrix will be a result of a data query from a website. The query return Pandas. So, how can I create a matrix using data from pandas at runtime?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 1):

try ..

```
import numpy as np
my_50x50_matrix_at_runtime = np.zeros((50, 50))
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything you do in Python is on runtime. If your response is a `pandas.DataFrame` you can just access it's `values` attribute to get the underlying numpy array. No need to create it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your dataFrame is:

```
In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
                   A         B         C         D
        0  0.469112 -0.282863 -1.509059 -1.135632
        1  1.212112 -0.173215  0.119209 -1.044236
        2 -0.861849 -2.104569 -0.494929  1.071804
        3  0.721555 -0.706771 -1.039575  0.271860
        4 -0.424972  0.567020  0.276232 -1.087401
        5 -0.673690  0.113648 -1.478427  0.524988
```

Just use df.values to get all data. Also you may want to reshape the data in-case it is not already a 50X50 matrix. You can reshape it using,

```
df.values.reshape(4,6) # in your case 50X50
```